# How to add buttons in custom keyboard extension programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm building a keyboard extension for iOS.

Currently I try to add the buttons/keys programatically like this:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 35, height: 20)

button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

button.layer.borderWidth = 2
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

If I try to run the app, the keyboard appears but no button/key is displayed. Do you know what's wrong with my code? 
So all in all I just want to know how I can add a button to my custom keyboard where `x = 15` and `y = 15`.

Comment: You already posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211391/how-to-add-buttons-in-custom-keyboard-extemsion-swift-programmatically) under a different account and then you deleted it. This version is no better than your previous post. If you want help, you need to update this question with more relevant code and a better description of the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question. Is it now understandable?